# Test method that was called from other method

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking, ruby-mocha

I have module Database with method generate_from_database that spins for loops and calls method get_length. How can I test if get_length was called n times, by using rspec or mocha?

```
module Database
class Length < ActiveRecord::Base
  def get_length(i,j)
    ...
  end
end
def Database.generate_from_database
  ...
for i in 0...size
  for j in 0...size
    Length.new.get_length(i+1,j+1))
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
mock_length = mock("length")
Length.should_receive(:new).exactly(n).times.and_return(mock_length)
mock_length.should_receive(:get_length).exactly(n).times
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could so something like:

`Length.should_receive(:get_length).exactly(n).times`

More info: http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/message_expectations.html

Comment: I did like that:
Length.should_receive(:get_length).exactly(10).times
Database.generate_from_database
and I got failures: was expected 10, received 0, but I know that generate_from_database calls 10 times get_length. So why rspec doesn't see calls?

Comment: @Mario. Just a shot in the dark, but perhaps its a namespace issue? Try Database::Length.

Comment: @Mark. Thanks for shot, but method generate_from_database isn't class Length method.. Maybe that's a problem

Comment: @Mario. Are you doing this with a mock?